# How to solve the login permission with two different premission?

Tags: php, html, authentication

I want to create a login system with premission 1 and 2 . Premission 1 go to index,and Premission 2 go to index2.But It can't login ,what's the problem?
here is the database and the logincheck.php show to u .

Database:

```
create database babytradeapps;

use babytradeapps;

create table loginacc (Bid int AUTO_INCREMENT,              
                    LoginID char (20),
                    Password char(30), 
                                        Permission INT NOT NULL,
                    PRIMARY KEY (Bid),
                                        UNIQUE(LoginID)
                    ) ;
insert into loginacc values('','baby','123456','1');
insert into loginacc values('','admin','admin','1');
insert into loginacc values('','example','example1','2');
insert into loginacc values('','example2','example2','2');
```

checklogin.php

```
<?php

      $name = $_GET['username'];
      $pass = $_GET['pass'];

      $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");

      mysql_select_db("babytradeapps");

      $sql = "Select * from loginacc
           where LoginID = '$name' 
             and Password = '$pass'"; 

     $returns = mysql_query($sql,$con);

      $num = mysql_num_rows($returns);

      $row = mysql_fetch_row($returns);

      $permission =  $row["permission"] ;


    if ($num !=0)  { 


   session_start();

      $_SESSION['login'] = 'success';

          $_SESSION['user'] = $name;

          $_SESSION['permission'] = $permission;


     if($permission == 1){
         header("Location:index.php");

   } else if($permission == 2){
      header("Location:index2.php");
   }

       } else { 

         header("Location:login.html");



      }

    ?>
```

what's problem??

Comment: No you need to tell us the problem in a minimal coded example... Also do not store passwords as plaintext, the code has sql injection holes and you should stop using mysql_* functions, they are deprecated.

Comment: Track this line `$permission =  $row["permission"]`  -> `$permission =  $row["Permission"]`  permission   `P` should be capital

Comment: should the db column definitions use 'varchar' rather than 'char'? Not sure if sql checks full length for 'char' columns.

Answer (score 0):

First view your data using `print_r`,

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($returns);
print_r($row);
```

You can see the result as array format. Replace `$permission =  $row["permission"] ;` with below code,

```
$permission =  $row[3] ;
```

and please refer **[mysql_fetch_row()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)**.